# Поиск текста по pdf файлу

Tags: android, pdf, search, android-search-view

Пишу маленькое приложение на андроид, которое открывает pdf файл. Cам pdf файл вшит в приложение. Хочу реализовать поиск текста по этому pdf файлу. Подскажите как правильно это реализовать?

Comment: использовал библиотеку https://github.com/barteksc/AndroidPdfViewer

Comment: поиск текста в pdf файле.